# Upgrading to Spree 2.0.0 Bundler dependency issues With Extensions that depends upon spree_core 1.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, spree

I'm trying to upgrade my spree store to spree new release 2.0.0 my gem file is as follow it gives me following error when i do "bundle install"
     Any clue?

```
Sample Error look like:
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
In Gemfile:
spree_social (>= 0) ruby depends on
  spree_core (~> 1.3.0) ruby

spree_auth_devise (>= 0) ruby depends on
  spree_core (2.0.0)

GemFile:
------------
# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', :github => 'spree/spree_gateway', :branch => '1-3-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-0-stable'
gem "spree_social", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_social.git", :branch => '1-3-        stable'
gem 'spree_active_sale' , :git => 'git://github.com/suryart/spree_active_sale.git',   :branch => '1-3-stable'
```

Further more, please tell me  should i wait for the newer versions of these extensions(spree-social etc.. mentioned above) to pull them from git hub that will depends upon "spree_core 2.0.0" ? or Alternatively should i make my on custom extension to achieve the functionalists provided by above spree extensions? Help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is spree_auth_devise which is dependent on spree_frontend (2.0.0.rc1)

Probable solution will be to look for branch which is dependant on spree_frontend 2.0.0 coz spree 2.0 depends on spree_frontend (2.0.0)

I looked into its git repo spree_auth_devise is still pointed to spree_frontend 2.0.0.beta

Comment: Thanks, But the problem is i'm using a bunch of spree extensions that depends upon spree_core 1.3.x when i do upgrade to (spree_core 2.0.0) all these extensions conflict with newer version of spree core as these extensions depend upon spree 1.3.X.

Comment: Yep that will and should happen according to there dependencies If u want to use those extension u will have to download the code and upgrade and test there gemspecs and then u will be able to use them ......

Comment: Hi I have added these issue on there repo you can refer and add ur queries....  https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/issues/92

Comment: I have resolved issue related to spree_auth_devise just pointing it to 2-0-stable branch.

Answer (score 0):

We forked a branch of `spree_auth` locally.

Modified the Gemfile as follows:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => '2-0-stable'
```

Modified the spree_social.gemspec as follows:

```
s.add_dependency 'spree_core', '~> 2.0.0'
```

Modified the Versionfile to reflect the branch:

```
"2.0.x" => { :branch => '2-0-temp' }
```

Bundled with no problem and permitted us to bundle our project with Spree 2-0-stable